# Javascript: Dojogrid save when user click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have this Dojogrid which has list of data per row , my problem is I want to save the edited rows when the user click other row or just click outside the grid. I don't want any save button or anything like that , I just want to make it simple.

I'm gonna call this function from my controller whenever the user click other row or just click outside the grid when he/she edited the row.

```
  public JsonResult Register(prmJuchu prm, bool alreadyDelivered)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: I'm looking through it right now But I can't seem to find the function that lets me save the data on grid when I click other rows or outside the grid.

Comment: Well, do you have the code to save?

Comment: yes , all I need now is the javascript that will let me detect when the user click other row and click outside the grid.